# Integrating moment of Inertia elements/Choosing the infinitesimal element for integration for a disc

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Moment of inertia is defined by this integral
$ I =\int r^2 dm$

where 
$I$ is the moment of inertia
$r$ is the distance from axis of rotation of a mass element 'dm'
r

Now, If I have a disc I could split it up into infinitesimal rings and integrate the rings along the length of radius

$I= \int_{0}^{r} r^2 M dr$

but this seems to give me the wrong answer, why?

What is wrong in my logic?

Comment: dm is $\rho dV$ where V is volume

Comment: I dont think the disc has volume it's a thin disc

Comment: But even is it’s thin you have volume?

Comment: For infinitely thin objects, think in terms of area rather than volume. The disk has some amount of mass per unit area. This is called a surface density and is usually written $\sigma$. So $dm=\sigma\,dA$. Between the answer and the comments, you have now gotten so many hints that you can finish your homework by yourself. We don’t provide complete homework solutions on this site.

Comment: I know this way to do it I asked to know why the method I attempted was wrong

Comment: My answer explains what you did wrong.

Comment: I said that so it was clear that I am NOT looking for homework solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle behind your technique to solve this problem is to first find the moment of inertia of a thin ring ($dI$), then integrate this to get I.

Now, the moment of inertia of an elemental ring is given by $dmr^2$. In the case of an elemental ring the radius is $dr$. Assume your disc has radius $R$ and mass $M$. Then, the surface mass density is $\frac {M}{\pi R^2}$. The mass $dm$ of this ring is given by:

$dm = \frac {M}{\pi R^2} \bullet 2\pi r \bullet dr$

This gives us:
 $I = \int\frac {M}{\pi R^2} \bullet 2\pi r dr \bullet r^2$.

Integrating, $I = \frac {MR^2}{2}$, which is the correct answer.

Comment: ah thank you , I made mistakes in taking the differential mass

Comment: To find the area of a thin ring, you always just multiply the infinitesimal thickness of the ring with the circumference.

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong in my logic?

The infinitesimal mass $dm$ of a ring of thickness $dr$ is not $M\,dr$. That doesn’t even have the dimensions of mass.

Comment: huh good point.. now how would I fix this?

Comment: You can figure out $dm$ based on the area of the ring.

Comment: I  meant the thin rings?